# How to make addin solution of outlook 2010 to work in outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook, add-in

I have developed addin solution for outlook 2010 that generates new tab on Message window, Here a message could be loaded on mail from word document by clicking on Button. It is working fine. Now i want my solution to function in outlook 2007 also. While deploying the solution through setup file, addin gets installed in outlook 2007 but the new tab is not seen and the addin seems inactive. What should I do to make my solution work in outlook 2007 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start with a  2007 addin, and it will work with 2007 and 2010.  You always need to target the lowest version you want to support.  The newer versions can load add ins from previous versions but not typically the other way around.